# loose leaf on dining room table

Tags: furniture

I have an old table with multiple leaves.  When the leaves are in, on one end of the basic table, the leaf fits tightly.  On the other end, no matter how you push it in, as soon as you let go, the end and the leaf pull away about 1/4".

Does anyone know of some kind of fastener I could mount underneath the inside edge of the table and the leaf to hold them together tighter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you want are called [table locks](http://woodworker.com/c-Hardware-table/table-locks/)

Answer (score 1):

[Not sure what the proper term is](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/71797/33), but a '*toggle latch*' or '*draw latch*' would work well.

[image]

[image]

They come in all shapes, sizes, colors, materials, and finishes.