# What is the proper term for a latch that uses a loop and lever to draw things together?

Tags: terminology

In [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/71796/33) I advised the OP to use what I called a '*toggle latch*' or '*draw latch*'. Do these things have a *proper* name?

[image: toggle latch] [image: draw latch]

Comment: Cabinet/box spring hasp?

Comment: @Gunner Don't think I'd use the word ["*hasp*"](https://www.google.com/search?q=hasp), since the definition doesn't quite fit. "*a slotted hinged metal plate that forms part of a fastening for a door or lid and is fitted over a metal loop and secured by a pin or padlock.*".

Comment: Maybe "*clasp*", or "*catch*".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the U.S. the item you refer to is most often called a [*draw catch*](http://www.stanleyhardware.com/detail/1844-lockable-draw-catches-s833-301). There are other names, depending on manufacturer and purpose, but I worked 19 years in commercial and residential hardware supply and we always called that a **draw catch**.

Answer (score -2):

I know them as an over centre latch.